# websocket-server replacement in BrowserQuest

Tags: node.js, websocket, npm, browserquest

I am trying to get Mozilla's [BrowserQuest](http://browserquest.mozilla.org) up and running and have run into a problem.  It depends on the `websocket-server` node package, and unfortunately that has been deprecated and removed from the npm library.

I have added the `ws` and `node-websocket-server` packages, however neither of them seem to be an easy replacement for the existing calls to `websocket-server`.

One prior SO post I saw said to replace `websocket-server` with `node-websocket-server` in the `package.json` file, however there are existing direct calls to `websocket-server` in the BrowserQuest codebase.

I also tried updating the `server/js/ws.js` file directly as follows (added node- to the websocket-server fields):

```
var cls = require("./lib/class"),
    url = require('url'),
    wsserver = require("node-websocket-server"),
    miksagoConnection = require('node-websocket-server/lib/ws/connection'),
    worlizeRequest = require('websocket').request,
    http = require('http'),
    Utils = require('./utils'),
    _ = require('underscore'),
    BISON = require('bison'),
    WS = {},
    useBison = false;
```

which leads to the following error:

```
/homenode/browserquest/BrowserQuest/server/js/map.js:15
        path.exists(filepath, function(exists) {
             ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at module.exports.cls.Class.extend.init (/home/node/browserquest/BrowserQuest/server/js/map.js:15:11)
    at Class (/home/node/browserquest/BrowserQuest/server/js/lib/class.js:50:23)
    at module.exports.cls.Class.extend.run (/home/node/browserquest/BrowserQuest/server/js/worldserver.js:151:20)
    at /homenode/browserquest/BrowserQuest/server/js/main.js:79:15
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/node/browserquest/BrowserQuest/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:153:9)
    at main (/home/node/browserquest/BrowserQuest/server/js/main.js:77:7)
    at /home/node/browserquest/BrowserQuest/server/js/main.js:134:13
    at /home/node/browserquest/BrowserQuest/server/js/main.js:117:13
    at fs.js:334:14
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is updated! I also got it to work today!!

https://github.com/nenuadrian/BrowserQuest